# R: Download all dependencies for different OS

Tags: r, package

I'm running Mac OS X, but the I need to get the windows binaries for several packages, together with all their dependencies.

I tried

```
install.packages('data.table', destdir='temp', dependencies=TRUE)
```

this will download the Mac OS compatible files into the folder `temp`. Is there any way to get the windows binaries instead, comfortably?

```
download.packages('data.table', destdir='temp', dependencies=TRUE,
+                      type='win.binary')
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  unused argument (dependencies = TRUE)
Warning in download.packages("data.table", destdir = "temp", dependencies = TRUE,  :
  download of package 'data.table' failed
```

Comment: Maybe the `type` argument...?

Comment: That  gives me 'Error in install.packages : cannot install Windows binary packages on this platform'. I should somehow tell it to only download, not install..

Comment: Use `download.packages` with `type = "win.binary"` or something similar

Comment: `download.packages` doesn't allow dependencies, as far as I can tell - and then also the error above happened.

Comment: This would give you the dependencies: `tools::package_dependencies("data.table", available.packages())`

Comment: For `data.table`, it gives me `[1] "methods"  "reshape2"`. Is that really all I need? I got an error earlier today about `plyr` being required.

Comment: See the `which` argument in `package_dependencies`. I think you want either `most` or `all`.

Comment: So Ill ask this shortly here, but maybe this needs to be a new question (I couldn't google this): To have a package running, the minimum requirement is 'most'? It seems like I need to have 'suggests' in their, or is there a way to run 'data.table.' without having 'plyr'

Comment: Try using the `miniCRAN` [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/index.html) - it was designed for this type of scenario.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to get the Windows binaries? Is this a case of "must sneaker-net to another machine"?  If so, you're probably just as well off manually D/L-ing from CRAN and checking the dependency lists at each package's webpage.

Comment: So, I have a "production" server where I have no administrative access and no write-access on. It runs on windows R `3.1.1`. I need to provide the administrator with all the required binary packages. They will provide me with a folder with all these packages, which I then will have to set up as lib path.

Comment: I suppose the administrator is too [something] to be willing to execute `install.packages` for you :-( ?

Comment: Yes and no. The server has no internet connection at all (really sensitive data), so it wouldn't really work..

Comment: @CarlWitthoft could you check whether my approach (as in the answer) is okay? I'm a little worried because the server also has `3.1`, but a potentially different subversion. Are the packages compatible? Are all packages that `packrat` takes as base, also provided as base under other versions of `3.1` and Windows?

Comment: I have tomorrow as the last chance to access the server before my window is up, and I don't want to leave anything to chance after blowing it today.

Answer (score 1):

So here is what I ended up doing.

I ran my project using `packrat`, while that installed all the packages in `packrat/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0/3.1.1`.

Then I ran the following code, as inspired by @jdharrison.

```
packages <- list.dirs('packrat/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0/3.1.1', full.names = FALSE, recursive=FALSE)

for (package in packages){
  download.packages(package, type='win.binary', destdir='winbinaries')
}
```